# How to build subset with looping codes using unique ID

Tags: r

I try to write a looping code with ID in a data.frame `df`.  what I did right now is I build another list dm which contains the unique ID from `df$ID`:

```
dm<-df %>% select(ID) %>% unique()
for (i in 1:length( dm$ID)){
   df_new<-df %>% filter(ID %in% dm$ID[i]) 
...
```

Current codes can do what I need. But I wonder whether there is another way to do it without building dm? I want to build subset by each ID in df. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over the `unique` 'ID' and `subset`ing, a faster option is `split` which will split the `data.frame` into `list` of data.frame based on the `unique` values of 'ID'

```
df_list <- split(df, df$ID)
```

From here, we can either use `lapply` or a `for` loop

```
pdf(paste0(out_dir, output_date,'.pdf')) 
for(i in seq_along(df_list)) {
     ggplot(data = df_list[[i]]) + 
           ...
    } 
dev.off()
```

Or with `lapply`

```
pdf(paste0(out_dir, output_date,'.pdf'))    
lapply(df_list, function(dat) 
        ggplot(data = dat) + 
           ...
    )
dev.off()
```

---

Regarding the creation of an object of `unique` 'ID', a better option is

```
for(un in unique(df$ID)) {
       df_new <- df %>%
                    filter(ID == un)
       ggplot(df_new) + 
           ...
  }
```

Comment: `split` can build a list which contain # of list = # unique `ID`. In this case, how should I do the looping? I try to make a plot for each dataset and out put them into one PDF.  My current codes are `pdf(paste0(out_dir,output_date,'.pdf'))
for (i in 1:length( dm$ID)){  
  df_new<-df %>% filter(ID %in% dm$ID[i]) 
  
  p1 <- ggplot(data =df)+... print(p1)
 
}

dev.off() `

Comment: @Stataq I updated with the `for` loop code.  As there is no example data, it is not tested

Comment: Thanks. `for` should work. How about `lapply`? if I want to try '`lapply`, what should I do? I feel building a list and then using `for` is more clear than my old method.  Big improvement.

Comment: `for` seems easier to follow. :P